# PowerShell creating a backup of a stored procedure results in a blank file

Tags: sql, powershell, stored-procedures, backup

I am trying to create a backup of a SQL stored procedure using PowerShell, but it produces a blank file. It's not throwing an error.

Here is my code:

```
param([String]$step='exeC dbo.test',[String]$sqlfile='',[String]$servename = 'test',[String]$dbname = 'test')
$step2=$step
$step3=$step2.Replace('[','')
$step4 = $step3.Replace(']','')
$step4 = $step4.Split(" ")[1]
$step5 = $step4.Split(".")
Write-Output  $step5[0,1]
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO”) | out-null

$logfolder = 'C:\Users\fthoma15\Documents\sqlqueries\Logs'
$bkupfolder = 'C:\Users\fthoma15\Documents\sqlqueries\Backup'
$statsfolder = 'C:\Users\fthoma15\Documents\sqlqueries\stats'
$SMOserver = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter") #-argumentlist $server 

$srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("$servename")
#Prompt for user credentials
$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $false
$credential = Get-Credential 

#Deal with the extra backslash character
$loginName = $credential.UserName -replace("\\","") 
#This sets the login name 
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_Login($loginName); 

#This sets the password 
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_SecurePassword($credential.Password)  

$srv.ConnectionContext.ApplicationName="MySQLAuthenticationPowerShell"  

#$srv.Databases | Select name
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
$db = $srv.Databases.Item("$dbname") 
#$db.storedprocedures | Select name
$Objects = $db.storedprocedures[$step5[1,0]]
#Write-Output  $step5[1,0]
#Write-Output $Objects
$scripter = new-object ("$SMOserver") $srv 
$Scripter.Script($Objects) | Out-File $bkupfolder\backup_$($step5[1]).sql
```

Please help

Comment: First thing to change: use straight quotes `"` around `“Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO”`, not the curly thingies.

Comment: @Theo , i think that changed when i copied it here, its already the straight ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with permission to the database. I gave the SQL id permission to the database and now it works.